# Does the brain always think of an appropriate response when reacting to a stimulus?

Tags: human-biology

Does the brain always think of an appropriate response when reacting to a stimulus?

For example, when seeing things, does the brain have to think of an appropriate response to the eyes?

Comment: From the two answers seems this really unclear question.

Comment: This question seems sort of oddly upvoted and answered - it is pretty low-quality and unclear what you are asking compared to the normal standards for Biology.SE. What does "appropriate" mean?

Comment: This is the most vague question I've ever come across. What are you on, exactly? And why was this upvoted?

Comment: @Servaes It was in Hot Network Questions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, not always but most of the time; reacting to stimuli is what defines the nervous system and the part of the nervous system that includes the brain is called the 'central nervous system' or CNS. Reactions to stimuli (nerve impulses) don't always have to pass through the brain as the CNS consists of the brain and the spinal cord. This means that in the case of thinking, if what you see (or sense) is something harmful (a man with a knife, feel extreme heat) then you will react without the nerve impulse having to pass through your brain (instead it will simply pass through your spinal cord). This is because the body does not need nor want to waste time thinking about an obvious and protective response. This reaction that requires no conscious thinking is called a 'reflex reaction' or an 'automatic reaction'. If you want to know more about this you should probably look into the nervous system.

Comment: If you take the stimuli as light entering the eye, then this answer is a bit misleading, since even basic object recognition (e.g. to identify dangerous objects) is going to be performed by visual cortex in the brain. Yes other parts of the response may not be in the brain, and even if in the brain, it is not too clear what the OP means by "think".

Comment: @NeilSlater: The contraction of the iris when the stimulus is *bright* light entering the eye is an interesting one. It does involve the midbrain, so it's not like the knee-jerk reflex that involves only the spinal cord. But it might serve as an example which the question doesn't consider under the heading "the brain *thinking* of a response", if "thinking" is intended to refer to activity of the cerebral cortex (including image-recognition). I do agree with you though: this answer says that the reaction to seeing a man with a knife involves only the spinal cord, not the brain, which is false.

Comment: ... in fact I think arguably the retinae could be considered part of the brain. In any case they connect to the brain via the optic nerves, and the spinal cord isn't in that path at all.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Not only is it false, there's still the whole question of whether the response the brain comes up with is actually appropriate.  Present the same "man with knife" stimulus to a random sample of people, and I think you're likely to get a wide range of responses.

Comment: @jamesqf of course it goes without saying that each individual's reaction will vary due to several factors: situation, environment raised in, personality, self-confidence, etc. However, it I no question that every single person WILL react and upon impulse too; since not a single person will do nothing at all (obviously)

Comment: @Lucas Dyson-Diaz: I don't know about that.  Seems like the reaction of many people to that sort of situation is simply to freeze, or "run in circles, scream and shout".

Comment: @jamesqf or fight back or call for help or team up on him or throw stuff at him from a safe distance or call the police or don't call the police or accept your death or try to reason with the man. There are more responses to any situation than just stand there or don't (I just named 8).

Comment: @jamesqf: I don't put too much weight on the word "appropriate" in the question: surely the question here is not intended to be, "are humans always right about everything?". If so it belongs on Philosophy. If you see someone with a knife and shoot them, then I think for the purpose of this question that was the "appropriate" response, that is to say the response the organism makes to a particular stimulus, regardless of whether the jury eventually decides it was "appropriate" or "inappropriate".

Comment: @Steve Jessop: But the OP is specifically asking about "appropriate response", no?  Certainly we could go into philosophical/legal discussions about what reaction is appropriate to any given circumstance, but I think it's pretty obvious that there are some reactions that are inappropriate by any reasonable standard.

Comment: @jamesqf . Whether it is appropriate is not a decision for any one or two people to decide. Especially in such a desperate and life-threatening situation, there is little you could call inappropriate (other than killing the man, possibly, however that could philosophically be argued as appropriate too).

Comment: @jamesqf: I would say "no", the questioner is not intentionally asking specifically about the "appropriate" response in the wider sense that you refer to when you describe "scream" as an inappropriate response. I think they just mean "appriopriate response" in a sense something like, "the neural response necessary to make the organism do whatever it is that it does in response to the stimulus". So if the organism screams in response to knife-wielders, then the "appropriate response" is to signal the lungs, throat, face, etc. Even if screaming is a dumb idea by any reasonable standard.

Answer (score 3):

**No:**

[image]

[Optical illusions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_illusion) trick your brain and elicit an inappropriate response. Of course optical illusions don’t need to be engineered, they abound in reality (remember [The Dress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dress) that went viral two years ago)?

In addition to optical illusions, other senses can be tricked. There are [auditory illusions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auditory_illusion), an [illusory sense of touch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tactile_illusion), etc.

Comment: I can barely look at that. What's actually going on in it? It's like it's moving. Wow! It's weird. Now it's sliding. It's worse if you focus your eyes, if you unfocus your eyes it's easier to look at. I still can't figure it out. What's it doing?

Comment: @DanielCann It’s really just straight, equidistant, parallel lines with black/white coloured square boxes between them. The sequences of boxes in each row are offset at different distances from the left side. That’s all there is to it.

Comment: How do you know? We're both human, and it's an optical illusion which is designed to deceive humans.

Comment: @DanielCann Well I mean you can simply check with a straightedge and a set square/triangle/compass …

Comment: @DanielCann: or assuming you trust your PC not to conspire with Konrad to trick you, zoom in on the image in any image-editing program. The illusion doesn't work on a small enough section. Then you'll see that nothing's moving and everything in any given small section of the image is straight and square. Pan around the image until you're convinced it's true everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is if thinking is **always a response to some external stimuli** depends if we consider the memory. Thinking about the event in the past is surely possible many years after the stimuli is long gone. Continuous stimuli from the environment may not be required for the thinking process itself as [spontaneous brain activity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_oscillation) exists as well.